# Opening the browser from Python running in Google Cloud Shell

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

I'm developing a small script on Python 3.6, and I'll most likely use it from Google Cloud Shell. In said script, I want to do some API calls, and then, open the web browser with an URL, result of those calls. The following code works in other environments that I have tested on, but not in Cloud Shell:

```py
import webbrowser as wb
# different calls and process here, not relevant to the issue 
wb.open('URL_HERE')
#This just echoes the URL.
```

Is there anyway to make Python 'tell' Cloud Shell to use the browser from where it's running? i.e: if I'm using Chrome to open Cloud Shell, is there any way to open the link in Chrome? It doesn't matter if it's with webbrowser or other library.

Answer (score 2):

Cloud Shell is just a “window” displaying a command line from a remote and [temporary Compute Engine virtual machine instance](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/features#virtual_machine_instance). Meaning that when you run the script, you are actually running it in the remote VM (not in Chrome), and that specific VM does not have a browser by itself.

For example, when you try to run an app in Cloud Shell ([here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/quickstart#running_hello_world_on_your_local_machine) you can find a quick example using "mvn appengine:run"), once the application is running, you will see a message in Cloud Shell, something like:

[INFO] GCLOUD: INFO: Module instance default is running at http://localhost:8080/

If you click on http://localhost:8080/ , you will actually be redirected to the temporary address assigned for the Cloud Shell VM instance (something like 8080-dot-VM-ID-devshell.appspot.com).

In summary, you can’t command Cloud Shell to open the browser with a specific URL shown in the remote VM command line. Also, you should consider that there are [outgoing connections limitations](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/limitations)  and Cloud Shell is intended for [interactive use](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/limitations#usage_limits) only.